# Fastest way to check if an array contains the same objects of another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, fast-enumeration

The goal is to compare two arrays as and check if they contain the same objects (as fast as possible - there are lots of objects in the arrays). The arrays cannot be checked with `isEqual:` as they are differently sorted.

I already tried the solution posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138417 - see last code snippet of the post by Peter Hosey). But this doesn't work with differently sorted arrays.

The code I'm using now is the following:

```
+ (BOOL)arraysContainSameObjects:(NSArray *)array1 andOtherArray:(NSArray *)array2 {
    // quit if array count is different
    if ([array1 count] != [array2 count]) return NO;

    BOOL bothArraysContainTheSameObjects = YES;
    for (id objectInArray1 in array1) {
        BOOL objectFoundInArray2 = NO;
        for (id objectInArray2 in array2) {
            if ([objectInArray1 isEqual:objectInArray2]) {
                objectFoundInArray2 = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!objectFoundInArray2) {
            bothArraysContainTheSameObjects = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    return bothArraysContainTheSameObjects;
}
```

This works, but those are two nested fast enumerations. Is there a way to do a faster comparison?

Comment: Do you also have to verify that it has the same number of matching objects?  For example if array 1 has 2 instances of X, but array 2 only has 1 then it fails?

Comment: Yes, this should also be verified.

Comment: In that case you have no choice but to sort them both and compare them.

Comment: Does this help: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/168144-finding-out-if-an-nsarray-contents-are-all-equal.html - `- (unsigned)numberOfDistinctObjects
{
    return [[NSSet setWithArray:self] count];
}`

Comment: @borrrden: OK, how about time complexity when sorting both arrays and comparing them afterwards with `isEqualToArray:`?

Comment: Well, it would be O(n) for the comparision, plus the efficiency of the sort algorithm.

Comment: If unequal is fairly likely you can do a quick check for that by hashing each entry and xoring the hash values, then comparing.  Not much help if unequal is rare, though.

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15269497/1635315). Its really helpful.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As per your code, you are strict to same number of elements and each object of first array should be there in second array and vice versa.

The fastest way would be to sort both the array and compare them.

Ex:

```
NSArray *array1=@[@"a",@"b",@"c"];
NSArray *array2=@[@"c",@"b",@"a"];

array1=[array1 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
array2=[array2 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]) {
    NSLog(@"both have same elements");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"both having different elements");
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed... similar thoughts.

Comment: @AKV Hmmm I analysed and later understood that its the best method and alternatives also take same time. :)

Comment: @FrankZp : You can also check like this, but not suggested as vague.

Comment: NSMutableArray *a1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
    NSMutableArray *a2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array2];
    
    [a2 removeObjectsInArray:a1];
    if ([a2 count]) {
        NSLog(@"Both are same");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Both are different");
    }

Comment: @AKV : Thanks for this comment - but I think I'm using the sorting and comparing with `isEqualToArray:` as this works really fine.

Comment: then how can i filter elements, say i have to add the elements into array1 from array2 like array2 = @[@"c",@"d",@"e",@"d"]; something like this..!

Answer (score 13):

How about converting both arrays to sets and comparing them.

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:arr1];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:arr2];
```

Compare the two using

```
if([set1 isEqualToSet:set2]) {

}
```

Comment: I also considered this way, but it won't work if the conditions of my comment are valid.

Comment: U were a step ahead @borrden :)

Comment: This is the right answer if you aren't concerned about multiple instances of the same object in an array.

Answer (score 3):

Use containsObject: method instead of iterating the whole array.

```
NSArray *array;
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Nicola", @"Margherita",                                       @"Luciano", @"Silvia", nil];
if ([array containsObject: @"Nicola"]) // YES
  {
    // Do something
  }
```

like this

```
+ (BOOL)arraysContainSameObjects:(NSArray *)array1 andOtherArray:(NSArray *)array2 {
    // quit if array count is different
    if ([array1 count] != [array2 count]) return NO;

    BOOL bothArraysContainTheSameObjects = YES;

    for (id objectInArray1 in array1) {

        if (![array2 containsObject:objectInArray1])
        {
            bothArraysContainTheSameObjects = NO;
            break;
        }

    }

    return bothArraysContainTheSameObjects;
}
```

Comment: `containsObject`'s complexity is often linear in the worst case (even when the arrays are sorted), so this is not asymptotically more efficient than the two nested fast enumerations.

Comment: @DanielMartín Hmmm I agree. And as borrrden rightly said , only option is to sort and compare.

Comment: However, this approach can potentially exit much sooner, if it's highly likely that arrays are unequal.

Answer (score 3):

Tried to get the accepted answer working but it wasn't quite the best fit for my situation.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242588/sortedarrayusingselector-what-is-it-doing) and all credit goes to @joel kravets for the method.

Basically sorting using a comparator enables you to sort using objects more easily - hence the problem I was facing when trying to use the above solution.

```
NSArray * array1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:users];
NSArray * array2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:threadUsers];

id mySort = ^(BUser * user1, BUser * user2){
    return [user1.name compare:user2.name];
};

array1 = [array1 sortedArrayUsingComparator:mySort];
array2 = [array2 sortedArrayUsingComparator:mySort];

if ([array1 isEqualToArray:array2]) {
    NSLog(@"both are same");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"both are different");
}
```

Previously I had tried to use other answers like those above, using break to go through loops but in the end this answer came out easiest probably due to its speed and also that in the end we have the if statement allowing us to put code depending on if they are the same or different.

Thanks to Anoop for getting me on the right track and Joel for helping me to tighten the efficiency of it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether both arrays contain the same duplicates, just use NSCountedSet. It's like an NSSet, but each object in the set also has a count telling you how often it has been added. So

```
BOOL same = (array1.count == array2.count);
if (same && array.count > 0)
{
    NSCountedSet* set1 = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array1];
    NSCountedSet* set2 = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array2];
    same = ([set1 isEqual: set2]);
}
```

No matter how you do it, this will be time consuming, so you might consider if there are special cases that can be handled quicker. Are these arrays usually the same, or almost the same, or is it true 99% of the time that they are different and that 99% of the time a random element of array1 is not in array2? Are the arrays often sorted? In that case, you could check whether there are identical objects in identical positions, and then consider only those objects that are not the same. If one array contains objects a, b, c, d, e and the other contains a, b, x, d, y, then you only need to compare the array [c, e] vs. [x, y].

Answer (score 1):

This way the complexity is O(N^2), if you follow this approach you can't do it with a lower complexity. While instead you can do it with O(N log(N)) if you sort both arrays and then compare them. This way after having them sorted you will do it using isEqualToArray: in other N operations.

Comment: I suppose that I'll have to sort both arrays? If the first array is unsorted and the other array is sorted, I guess that `isEqualToArray` will not return YES if the same objects are contained? (edit: just saw that borrrden added this as a comment to the first post ;) )

Comment: Sorry, I thought that one was sorted, fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[docTypes containsObject:@"Object"];
```

It will works for your req.  As early as fast it will return boolean value for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *filtered = [someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someParamter == %@", paramValue]]];
if (filtered.count) {

}
```

the main plus is you can use it for any kind of objects: custom, system, NSDictionary. for example I need to know is my UINavigationController's stack contains MySearchResultsVC and MyTopMenuItemsVC or not:

```
    NSArray *filtered = [self.navigationController.viewControllers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                                     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class IN %@",
                                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [MySearchResultsVC class],
                                       [MyTopMenuItemsVC class],
                                       nil]]];
if (filtered) {
/* ok, now we can handle it! */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but i just wanna share what i did..

```
NSString *stringArr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array1];
NSString *stringArr2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array2];

if ([stringArr1 isEqual: stringArr2])
    NSLog(@"identical");
else
    NSLog(@"not");
```

this is just like comparing **"@[@1,@2,@3,@4]" == "[@3,@2,@1,@4]"**.. which is obviously false..

Answer (score -5):

i guess this will do:

```
[array1 isEqualToArray:array2];
```

returns bool;

Comment: NSArray class reference says for `isEqualToArray:`: "Two arrays have equal contents if they each hold the same number of objects and objects at a given index in each array satisfy the isEqual: test." - As the arrays are differently sorted I suppose the method will return NO even when the same objects are in both arrays but with a different sort.