# Compare two array to get index of containing object

Tags: arrays, ios7, nsarray, nspredicate

Its really a simple question but I want a short way to compare two array to get index of containing object. For example we have two arrays....

```
NSArray *array1=@[@"b",@"a",@"c"];
NSArray *array2=@[@"c",@"b",@"a"];
```

After comparison from array2 to array1, I want the index of the containing object in array1.

I tried to check the this link but I didn't get ans as I expected
[Fastest way to check if an array contains the same objects of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935233/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-array-contains-the-same-objects-of-another-array)

Comment: if you just want to compare identity than use `[array indexOfObject:obj1]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if an array contains the same objects of another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935233/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-array-contains-the-same-objects-of-another-array)

Comment: But first i need to compare the two array and and when i will get the same object then I need to find out the index of that object.

Comment: So you want to get the objects that are present in array1 and array2 and then get the index of these objects in array1? Or in both arrays?

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya: It isn't duplicate, I already checked the ans in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935233/fastest-way-to-check-if-an-array-contains-the-same-objects-of-another-array and also mention above... I want index of object after comparing the two arrays. Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly right @MichałCiuba

Comment: @AG.IS: "I want index of object after comparing the two arrays" what does that even mean? For every item in array1 check with `[array1 indexOfObject:item]` if it is present in array2 and if it is just use that index

Comment: @Argent: It means I have two arrays which contains same objects. So I want to compare each other and when i will find the objects which are same in both array at that situation i want the index of the found object from array 1.

Comment: @AG.IS: you got plenty of answers to do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting indexes of objects in `array1` which are also present in `array2`, you can use:

```
NSIndexSet* indexes = [array1 indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [array2 containsObject:obj];
}];
[indexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Index is %u", idx);  //do whatever you need to do with the index
}];
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal. This answer is what i expected. Short and simple. Thanks for helping..God bless you..

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to get compare index from array 1 :

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayFirst = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"b",@"a",@"c", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arraySecond = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"c",@"b",@"a", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayComparedIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i =0; i<[arrayFirst count]; i++)
    {
         if ([arraySecond containsObject:[arrayFirst objectAtIndex:i]])
         {
                NSLog(@"index - %d",i);
                [arrayComparedIndex addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"arraythree - %@",arrayComparedIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks Divya But please could you tell me the way without using for loop. Is it possible?? I am finding the way without using loop. Nice solution Thanks..

Comment: @AG.IS, how do you mean _without loop_? there is no solution for your problem in `O(1)` time.

Comment: I mean i want to avoid For loop or you can say that i want short line ans. Like Michał Ciuba.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {
        NSString *s = array1[i];
        NSInteger anIndex = [array2 indexOfObject:s];

        NSLog(@"Index of %@ is: %d", s, anIndex);

        if (NSNotFound == anIndex) {
            NSLog(@"not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its working only in case , when both array have same number of object. May be its not working, when number of objects are not same for both array. Its give crash when array1 count is greater that the array2 count.

Comment: It is a simple answer to the simple question, of course you can do length checks also but that was not part of the question and is not that difficult to figure out

Comment: Thanks @ClemensL, But is it any shortest trick for this situation